# i am reading this api response using request , how do i get each item and the values as it is not list

Tags: python, json

```
{
  'financialData': {
    'maxAge': 86400,
    'currentPrice': {
      'raw': 315.01,
      'fmt': '315.01'
    },
    'targetHighPrice': {
      'raw': 370.8,
      'fmt': '370.80'
    },
    'targetLowPrice': {
      'raw': 207.77,
      'fmt': '207.77'
    },
    'targetMeanPrice': {
      'raw': 308.91,
      'fmt': '308.91'
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output/result?

Answer (score 3):

This is an implementation of a recursive function which prints the keys, values of each pair:

```
a = {...} # your dictionary

def recursive_items(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from recursive_items(value)
        else:
            yield key, value

c = list(recursive_items(a))
print(c)
# output 
[('maxAge', 86400), ('raw', 315.01), 
 ('fmt', '315.01'), ('raw', 370.8), 
 ('fmt', '370.80'), ('raw', 207.77),
 ('fmt', '207.77'), ('raw', 308.91), ('fmt', '308.91')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is not complete. I don't know if this is what you want,
look at this:

```py
for key,value in data.financialData.items()
        print(key,value)
```

Comment: i get this response when i do a get from finance api, so i wanted to to get one value in the the list , which i am trying and , these are not key value format if i see it, Thank you